# How can I map Alt-< or Alt->?

Tags: key-bindings

I try to create a mapping for `Alt <` and `Alt >`:

```
inoremap <M-<> foo-bar-baz
inoremap <M->> baz-bar-foo
```

This doesn't work, most probably because `<` and `>` are themselves characters used to define the mapping. So, how can I create such a mapping?

Comment: I would say that pressing `<Alt-<>` and `<Alt->>` insert another character the one you would expected, so I could explain your issue... e.g. on my computer it insert respectivly `¯` and `˘`

Comment: In insert mode, press `Ctrl+V` then `Alt+<`. What is inserted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As said in my comment, the `<Alt-X>` combination insert a special character. So instead of mapping to `<Alt-X>`, you can map it to the special character.

So

```
inoremap <M-<> foo-bar-baz
inoremap <M->> baz-bar-foo
```

becomes

```
inoremap ¯ foo-bar-baz
inoremap ˘ baz-bar-foo
```

Note : This was working on a Mac, on iterm2, tmux and macvim. The behaviour may change depending the configuration ...

Edit :  You can look at those posts :

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5379837/is-it-possible-to-mapping-alt-hjkl-in-insert-mode
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7501092/can-i-map-alt-key-in-vim

Comment: FYI, with xterm on Linux I get `0x1b 0x3e` and `0x1b 0x3c` With `Alt+<` and `Alt+>` (in other words, I get the expected Esc+key, instead of the MACRON and BREVE characters).

Comment: @Carpetsmoker Depending on your keyboard settings, you may need to use <ALTGR> to type those letters. And you can also map them. With ALTGR i get 'ł€¶ŧ←↓→øþæßðđŋħł«»¢“”nµ·' (and others) that I can map to vim goodness. I can also get ' ̈́' but have managed to type UpperBar yet.

Comment: @AlexStragies AltGr and Alt are different keys. Alt+character sends ESC followed by that character on most terminals, translated from the Alt+key keychord by the terminal emulator. AltGr+character inserts a different character which depends on the keyboard layout and is managed by the OS/GUI environment, not by the terminal emulator.

Comment: @Gilles, I was aware of the ability to (exit Insert Mode+<CMDKEY>) with ALT-CMDKEY, because it sends <ESC> <CMDKEY>. I was trying to point out how to get many mappable characters with ALTGR. For me the 2 Keys from the OP example require ALTGR